# Can't call JavaScript function on a radio button value change

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, scope, dom-events

I'm editing an ascx where I have a modal popup with a radio button. 
When the radio value changes I want to call a JavaScript function, but the function is not working. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
function UcSelect() {
    var value = $("#<%= rbtTipo.ClientID %> :checked").val();
    if (value == 'E') {
        alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    }
    if (value == 'G') {
        alert("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

and the button inside the popup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtTipo" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 8px;" onclick="UcSelect();" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="E">&nbsp; Nuovo Coefficiente Energia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="G">&nbsp; Nuovo Coefficiente Gas</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Taking a look in the debugger I found this message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError:
>        UcSelect is not defined onclick @ CoefficientiPage.aspx:1

**UPDATE:**

Instead, if I put the code (modified) here below in the ascx which contains the popup, I get the alert **Hello1**, but also this error:

> GET http://ajax.go/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

```
<script>
function UcSelect() {
    alert('hello1');
    if ($("#rbtTipo :checked").val() == 'E') {
        alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

How does js scope works? I'm confused.

Comment: Where have you given your `<script>` tag? If you can give your `<script>` tag with the function definitions at the start of the body, it will get called.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `onClientClick` to define client-side events from an ASP.NET page.

If you can, use that property. If not, read on.

Most probably, `RadioButtonList` does not have such a property, so you are left with a kind of hack: envelope the control in a non-`runat="server"` DOM element:

```
<div onclick="UcSelect();">
    <!-- your ASP control goes here -->
</div>
```

In other words your problem is this:

> The `onclick` event is interpreted as a server-side C# function.

Because you're writing cross-technology code (JS and ASP.NET) you'll be better off taking *also* a look at the rendered HTML page. From there, you should be able to figure out both sides of the problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm not sure i did understand. If i take the script and put it in the ascx where the popup is included it works, but the debugger print this message: ailed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: That looks like a different problem. As long as it works, you are one step forward. To solve that new problem you should show more code and a description, possibly in a new question.

Comment: ok, thanks, but why the function works in a different file? the scope of js is  strange